# Change JavaScript tag description

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

The current `javascript` tag excerpt reads thus:

`The common name for the language used primarily for scripting in web browsers. It is NOT related to Java. Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its dialects/ implementations: JavaScript, JScript, etc., excluding ActionScript.`

I noticed that there are over two thousand questions tagged `node.js`. Perhaps the description could be a little more general, especially since JavaScript is now relatively commonly used in other scripting environments, such as:

- Gnome 3
- v8- node.js
- rhino (used in Gnome 3)

The full description (tag wiki) mentions Rhino, but the excerpt only mentions web browsers.

**Would it make sense to remove the `used primarily for scripting in web browsers` part and put something more general there like `used as a general purpose scripting language, especially in modern web browsers`?**

I think mentioning that it is an interpreted language could also be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to edit the tag description yourself (or at least suggest an edit) by clicking the [improve description](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/3) link on the tag info page

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but it will have to go to an edit pool. Should I ask questions like this on meta or should I just go ahead and edit?

Comment: @tjameson Just edit, that's the whole reason that feature exists

Comment: Alright cool, I'll do that.